# Consulta a dos tablas con el mismo Folio SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

En la tablax inserto dos filas con el mismo folio y en la TablaY inserto el mismo folio pero con diferente Archivo(.png, .jpg, .doc etc)

Si inserto dos Folios en mi primer tabla y ese mismo folio lo inserto en la segunda tabla con datos diferentes.

Como puedo hacer la consulta para juntar las columnas de las dos tablas en una sola tabla y obtener solo dos filas ya que son las unicas que hay con el mismo folio?.

Con el siguiente codigo me los trae pero me los duplica, por ejemplo tengo un solo folio (Folio 1 con dos registros) para dos registros y cuando hago este query me trae los dos registros de la primera tabla y tambien los dos registros de la segunda tabla o sea 4 filas cuando solo espero 2 filas.

```
SELECT R.ITEM, R.FOLIO,R.NOMBRE,A.ARCHIVO,A.NOMBRE,A.TIPOARCHIVO
FROM TABLAX as R, TABLAY as A
WHERE R.FOLIO = A.FOLIO
```

Intente con `Inner Join` y me da el mismo resultado...

**EDITADO**:
Este es el resultado que obtengo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podran ver se estan duplicando.

Comment: Ya edite la pregunta y puse un ejemplo del resultado que obtengo

Comment: Solo las dos primeras filas de la imagen...analizando un poco las tablas, creo que como folo les estoy poniendo el mismo folio, necesito comparar guardar el nombre de la Archivo en ambas tablas o el ITEM para poder obtener cada fila con su Archivo o algo mas o menos asi, porque a como lo tengo, como el folio es el mismo los archivos se duplican y creo que ahi esta el problema, pero si tienes algo diferente con gusto probaria.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurren dos opciones:

1. Indicando en la tabla de ITEMS la persona asociada.
2. Indicando en la tabla PERSONA los items asociados.

OPCIÓN 1

```
    -- TABLA PERSONA
    SELECT FOLIO, NOMBRE
    FROM TABLAX

    -- TABLA ITEMS ASOCIADO A PERSONA
    SELECT FOLIO, ITEM, ARCHIVO, NOMBRE, TIPOARCHIVO
    FROM TABLAY

    -- CONSULTA
    SELECT A.ITEM, R.NOMBRE, R.FOLIO, A.NOMBRE, A.ARCHIVO, A.TIPOARCHIVO
    FROM TABLAX AS R RIGHT JOIN TABLAY AS A
    ON R.FOLIO = A.FOLIO
```

OPCIÓN 2

```
    -- TABLA PERSONA ASOCIADA A ITEM
    SELECT ID_ITEM, FOLIO, NOMBRE
    FROM TABLAX_2

    -- TABLA ITEMS
    SELECT ID_ITEM, ARCHIVO, NOMBRE, TIPOARCHIVO
    FROM TABLAY_2

    -- CONSULTA
    SELECT A.ITEM, R.FOLIO, R.NOMBRE, A.ARCHIVO, A.NOMBRE, A.TIPOARCHIVO
    FROM TABLAX_2 AS R LEFT JOIN TABLAY_2 AS A
    ON R.ID_ITEM = A.ID_ITEM
```

Ejemplo de opciones 1 y 2:

```
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TABLAX]    Script Date: 09/07/2019 22:54:30 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLAX](
        [FOLIO] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
        [NOMBRE] [nvarchar](50) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TABLAX_2]    Script Date: 09/07/2019 22:54:30 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLAX_2](
        [FOLIO] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
        [NOMBRE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [ID_ITEM] [varchar](1) NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TABLAY]    Script Date: 09/07/2019 22:54:30 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLAY](
        [FOLIO] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
        [ITEM] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [ARCHIVO] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [NOMBRE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [TIPOARCHIVO] [nvarchar](50) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TABLAY_2]    Script Date: 09/07/2019 22:54:30 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    SET ANSI_PADDING ON
    GO
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLAY_2](
        [ID_ITEM] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
        [ITEM] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [ARCHIVO] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [NOMBRE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
        [TIPOARCHIVO] [nvarchar](50) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
    SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
    GO
    INSERT [dbo].[TABLAX] ([FOLIO], [NOMBRE]) VALUES (N'1', N'JUANITO')
    INSERT [dbo].[TABLAX_2] ([FOLIO], [NOMBRE], [ID_ITEM]) VALUES (N'1', N'JUANITO', N'1')
    INSERT [dbo].[TABLAX_2] ([FOLIO], [NOMBRE], [ID_ITEM]) VALUES (N'1', N'JUANITO', N'2')
    INSERT [dbo].[TABLAY] ([FOLIO], [ITEM], [ARCHIVO], [NOMBRE], [TIPOARCHIVO]) VALUES (N'1', N'CAMARA', N'0xFF', N'Panasonic', N'.jpg')
    INSERT [dbo].[TABLAY] ([FOLIO], [ITEM], [ARCHIVO], [NOMBRE], [TIPOARCHIVO]) VALUES (N'1', N'COMPUTADORA', N'0x89', N'Computadora', N'.png')
    INSERT [dbo].[TABLAY_2] ([ID_ITEM], [ITEM], [ARCHIVO], [NOMBRE], [TIPOARCHIVO]) VALUES (N'1', N'CAMARA', N'0xFF', N'Panasonic', N'.jpg')
    INSERT [dbo].[TABLAY_2] ([ID_ITEM], [ITEM], [ARCHIVO], [NOMBRE], [TIPOARCHIVO]) VALUES (N'2', N'COMPUTADORA', N'0x89', N'Computadora', N'.png')
```